# Report Filter Question: Display all records inserted after certain time from datetime field

Tags: reporting, formula

I'm trying to put a formula in filter of report and and having difficulty writing it as I'm new to salesforce world. Here is the scenario:

Any record if inserted after 3pm yesterday should be displayed. There is a "Inserted__C" datetime field. I can compare against that.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: In report you can use Last N Days to get in day but for hour I am not sure.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to create that type of formula on a report filter. The closest that you can do is create a formula field on the object itself. Here's a post from the Success community that explains how to accomplish this:
https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gnsyAAA

Here is a link to all of the relative date values possible in Salesforce report criteria which sadly only provides days, not hours:
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_dates.htm&type=0

Comment: I was able to create custom field to achieve this: if( ISNULL( InsertedDate__C),false , DATETIMEVALUE( TEXT( TODAY() - 1 )+ " 23:00:00" ) < InsertedDate__C ). The only problem with this field is that some customer are located in different timezone. and we want to display their records based on Inserteddate__C ( some uses CST, EST, PST etc). I'm wondering how can I make 23:00:00 dynamic based on the client timezone? inserteddate is storing datetime in CST.

Comment: Here's what I found: https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000181642

Comment: I meant to add that I have never tried this myself and do not know if it applies for your situation.